# Railsのsaveメソッドがうまく動作しないです。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html

Railsにてアプリを作っております。初心者です。

現在

- Topモデル
- Trouserモデル
- Shoeモデル
- Collectionモデル

があり、

- @top
- @trouser
- @shoe

  はそれぞれCarrierWaveでアップロードされた、 :top_image, :trouser_image, :shoe_image のプロパティを持っています。

CollectionコントラローラーのnewのビューページではTop, Trouser, Shoeモデルからインスタンスを取得し、画像を一覧表示しています。

```rb
.d-block 
  = form_with model: @collection, url: collections_path , local: true do |f|
    .form-check
      - @tops.each do |top|
        = image_tag "#{top.top_image.url}"
        = label_tag :top_image
        =f.radio_button :top_image, top.top_image , checked: false
    .form-check
      - @trousers.each do |trouser|
        = image_tag "#{trouser.trouser_image.url}"
        =f.label :trouser_image
        =f.radio_button :trouser_image, trouser.trouser_image,  checked: false
    .form-check
      - @shoes.each do |shoe|
        = image_tag "#{shoe.shoe_image.url}"
        =f.label :shoe_image
        =f.radio_button :shoe_image, shoe.shoe_image, checked: false
    =f.submit '登録', class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

ここで、ラジオボタンでチェックされた:~~_imageをそれぞれ１枚ずつ、Collectionコントローラーで受け取り、ワンセットにしてCollectionに保存したいです。
しかし、params経由で受け取るところまでは良いのですが、受け取った後に@collectionに対してsaveメソッドを呼ぶと、@collectionがnillだとエラーが出ます。

debuggerを挟んで検証してみましたが、@collectionは値を保持しているのにも関わらず、saveメソッドを実行するとダメです(nilエラー）。

```rb
class CollectionsController < ApplicationController

...

　def new
　　@collection = Collection.new
　　@tops = Top.all
　　@trousers = Trouser.all
　　@shoes = Shoe.all
　end

  def create
    @collection = Collection.new(collection_params)

    # ここの行にて　p @collection や　debugger でparamsの値を確認すると、しっかり値を保持しています。
    # ですが、下記のように@collectionに対してsaveメソッドを呼び出すと、
    # undefined method `save' for nil:NilClassが出ます。
    # しかし、debuggerのコンソール内で@collection.saveを実行するとCOMMITしました。

    if @colletion.save
      flash.notice = 'コレクションを登録しました。'
      redirect_to collections_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private
    def collection_params
      {
        top_id: params[:collection][:top_image],
        trouser_id: params[:collection][:trouser_image],
        shoe_id: params[:collection][:shoe_image]
      }
　　　# StrongParameterを使った 
     # params(:collection).permit(:top_image, trouser_image, shoe_image)
     # でも動作しませんでした。
    end
end
```

ここ丸２日悩まされております...。
どなたか原因が分かる方はいらっしゃいますでしょうか？

Comment: `@colletion.save`は`c`が抜けているようです。正しくは、`@collection.save`だと思いますので確認してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます！解決しました！　まさかこんな初歩的なミスはしないだろうと思ってはいたのですが...。　ご指摘を受けてびっくりして声を上げてしまいました...。　とにかく、ありがとうございました！

Comment: おお、よかったです。私もたまにハマるので、なぜかnilになるときは、変数名をコピー＆ペーストして間違いないことを確認したりしてます。